# return array containing average of each of the specified columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been going crazy trying to find a way out.

Input a 2D array and several column numbers, return the average of every number in those specific columns in the form of array.

I know how to output the average of all columns, but I have no idea how to output only specific columns' averages.

a = array([[0, 0,1], [1, 1,2], [3, 3,3]])

get_average(a,[0,1])

array([1.333333333, 1.333333333333])

Answer (score 1):

#### Averaging in `numpy`

`numpy` has an `average` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0,1], [1, 1,2], [3, 3,3]])
>>> np.average(a[:,(0,1)], axis=0)
array([ 1.33,  1.33])
```

For `np.average`, `axis` specifies the array axis along with to average.  `axis=0`, for example, averages over the rows.

`np.average` also offers weighted averages if you ever need them.

#### Defining a `get_average` function

If you think you still want a `get_average` function, then:

```
def get_average(a, cols):
    return np.average(a[:,cols], axis=0)
```